# How to send Prometheus Alerts only for custom namespaces

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I would like to get prometheus alerts only for the namespaces that I deploy and exclude those ones from default namespaces like kube-system . Could some one help me how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just exclude the namespaces from which alerts are not needed in `expr` of your `alert_rule`, for example:

```
...
    alert: you_alert_name
    expr: sum(kube_pod_init_container_status_restarts_total{namespace!~"kube-public|kube-system|default|..."}[10s]) > 5
...
```